# What does sollen imply when used alone?

Tags: sentence-structure, verb-usage

When sollen verb is used alone in sentence, how is one supposed to know the meaning?

Examples:
1) Was soll ich damit?
Google translates as:
What should I do with that?
So in reality:
Was soll ich damit? = Was soll ich damit machen?

2) Zu Hause soll ich nicht.
Google translates as:
I'm not supposed to be at home.
So:
Zu Hause soll ich nicht. = Zu Hause soll ich nicht sein.

How do I "guess" the second verb? Are there any rules that I can learn for this case?
Thanks.

Comment: I would say, "find the most reasonable verb", but afaik it is not always so easy. Good question, imho.

Answer (score 3):

> Zuhause soll ich nicht.

is an appropriate answer for the request

> Üb' doch mal mehr, dann kannst du auch besser Geige spielen.

So, it's either clear from context (here: *üben* or *Geige spielen*), or it's the generic *tun* or *machen*.

(The translation google gives is plain wrong.)

Comment: It's debatable whether that's completely appropriate. It's colloquial at best. Usually a determiner would be used "Zuhause soll ich das nicht ..." and it would still be perceived as ellipsis so elision marks are needed.

Comment: In contrary, I think *Zuhause soll ich **es** nicht.* is so artifical no one would ever say it. Even if it's in the script.

Comment: Naja, ja, aber es klingt wie "ich muss mal", sehr häuslich, um es mal so auszudrücken.

Comment: Damit hast du sicher recht.

Comment: I would also hear "Sie soll aber!", but rarely "Sie soll!". In some way, *zuhause* plays the role of the object. I wouldn't hear "Ich soll nicht zuhause", where "zuhause" would, due to syntax, appear like a verb, but that's how it's parsed, I guess. "Spielen soll ich nicht".

Answer (score 3):

> Zu Hause soll ich nicht!

ergibt so isoliert keinen Sinn.

Der Satz - und speziell das **soll** bezieht sich auf das Verb des vorangehenden Satzes und kann nur im Kontext gedeutet werden.

> Zu Hause soll ich nicht!

does not make sense in isolation.

The sentence - and especially **soll** is supposed to refer to the verb of the preceding sentence and can only be interpreted in context.

google translation:
**https://translate.google.com/**

Comment: Kannst du deine Antwort vielleicht auf Englisch übersetzen oder ergänzen? Da der Fragende auch auf dieser Sprache nachfragt, ist nicht klar, ob er deutsche Antworten verstehen kann.

Comment: Ja, das kann ich. Aber die Frage ist: Soll ich?
Ich habe  heute erst erfahren, dass dies ein Konvenienz  von Höflichkeit ist, für Fremdsprachige auf englisch zu antworten. Ich werde diese Frage gleich in der meta stellen: Wenn jemand  in der Lage ist, sich auf SE zurecht zu finden und der englischen Sprache mächtig ist um eine knifflige Frage auf Deutsch zu stellen mit "google translates as" wird er auch eine Antwort mit Hilfe von verstehen. Er will letztlich doch Deutsch lernen, dann sollten wir uns nicht aus falscher Höflichkeit mit ihm in seiner Sprache unterhalten. Meine Überzeugung.

Answer (score 0):

The missing verb in the sentences is *tun* or *machen* (do).

For the first example

> Was soll ich damit?

is equivilent to

> Was soll ich damit machen?

So the translation

> What should I do with that?

is correct.

For the second example the translation you give is wrong.

If we add *machen* to the second example

> Zu Hause soll ich (etwas) nicht *machen*.

should make it clear that something is missing.

As the other answers already said, the sentence needs some reference to what I shouldn't do at home.

For example

> Kann ich hier Fußball spielen? Zu Hause soll ich nicht.
>
> Can I play soccer here? I shouldn't do it at home.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean "*Nach* Hause soll ich (nicht)"*? While in German you would probably rather say "Ich soll (nicht) nach Hause.". There is a "gehen", "fahren","fliegen", etc. implied by the use of "nach Hause" which is a direction/location. The condition of the speaker being at home ("Ich" "nach Hause") must be fulfilled ("soll"). So what is said is, that the speaker has to be at home (in forseeable future), but he leaves out by what means he achieves this.
The speaker doesn't want to bother you with uneccessary details, which is a typical example of german politeness ;o)

*) Nach vs. zu: You use 'zu' when it is a specified location (a supermarket), you use 'nach' when it is a undefined and/or geographical area (a town). "Nach Hause" could refer to one's actual home, but it could also just mean one's home-country, when you're abroad. It refers to what the speaker considers "home" at the given moment. (I think in English there is this ambiguity in the meaning of "home", too). So, "Ich gehe nach Hause", but "Ich gehe zu dem Haus, in dem Ich wohne". Yes, it is a bit confusing, most Germans mix it up from time to time, too.